# Minimizing profile curvature of 2D image

Tags: image-processing

I have 2D grayscale image representing terrain heights. I am in search
for (fast) algorithm to minimize profile curvature of this image on selected scales (in scale-space sense).

Profile curvature is function of partial derivatives:

$$P_c = - \frac{(dx^2 \times dxx + 2 \times dx \times dy \times dxy + dy^2 \times dyy)}{((dx^2 + dy^2) \times (dx^2 + dy^2 + 1)^{1.5})}$$

and its geometrical meaning is nicely explained by this image:
[image: Processed data]

I came up with completely ad-hoc iterative approach to minimize curvature 
at specified scale, but I am little bit lost when trying to apply this accross
all scales (I am trying to utilize Gaussian / Laplacian image pyramids). It works by adjusting heights by adding height offset according to profile curvature at given point (height offset is negative in convex areas and positive in concave areas).

Results for single scale are not completely hopeless though:

Original data:
[image: Original data]

Processed data:
[image: Processed data]

Result of this procedure should be formation of sharp V-shaped ridges
and valleys.

Is there any mathematically sound approach how to solve this kind of problems ?
Any tips are appreciated !

Comment: Can I please ask if you are interested in modifying the height map data or simply generating a representation of the original data for visualisation purposes only?

Comment: I want to modify height map data. I am working on digital terrain generation software which combines various 'filters' on source heightmap to produce final result, which is in turn used for visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am in search for (fast) algorithm to minimize profile curvature of this image on selected scales (in scale-space sense).
>
> ...
>   ... to minimize curvature at specified scale, [...], trying to apply this accross all scales (I am trying to utilize Gaussian / Laplacian image pyramids). It works by adjusting heights by adding height offset according to profile curvature at given point (height offset is negative in convex areas and positive in concave areas).

Modifications of curvature are basically modifications of a "signal's" dynamics.

In effect, what you are trying to say is "If the signal is rising (or falling) faster (or slower) than some threshold then...do something different". This "do something different" can be anything from "don't respond" to "respond slower" or "respond faster" and so on.

In one dimension, the [Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm does more or less what you are after.

The algorithm takes only one parameter which you can relate to the scale of observation but essentially modifies the local slope so that it remains within certain limits.

Variants that do [surface simplification](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a461098.pdf), or [mesh simplification](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/08_Simplification.pdf) exist too (or [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1524070300905307), in the case of contours) which use some expression of "cost" or "stress" to decide which element to remove during the simplification.

If you are "tied" to a height map (i.e. implicit 3D data), then you are looking at removing data (i.e. decimation) and interpolating / filtering. For example, you can use your $P_c$ to "mark" the areas of high or low curving slope in one pass and compute the "fill-in" values of each patch on a second pass. For examples of these approaches, you might want to take a look at [this](https://www.ariel.ac.il/sites/bmboaz/publications/ICTS_v0.29.pdf) or [this](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gotsman/AmendedPubl/Alex/3dpvt04.pdf) or more generally [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=height+field+simplification).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some very good tips provided ! Many thanks for that !

Comment: @born49 Thanks for letting me know, glad to hear it was helpful. You can upvote or accept the answer from the controls on the left which will also prevent this question circulating on the dsp.se as "unanswered".

Comment: I tried to upvote your response immediately, but unfortunately I have too low reputation to make upvote publicly visible.